# talend tFTPGet error can't find what the error string is

Tags: talend

I am developing a talend job with tFTPGet to fetch a file.
When i try to run the job in to test out the code, a error is reported . How do i see what the exact error is to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the error message of the TFTPGet component in a user code component:

[image: khaled khlifi]

The code of TJava will be executed only if the TFTPGet failed, you can use this line of code:

```
System.out.println(((String)globalMap.get("tFTPGet_1_ERROR_MESSAGE")));
```

Then you will see the error message in your console.

Comment: Thanks! I am going to try this out. I should use this for other problems in talend